# Can we see/detect things which don't have electrons

Tags: optics, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation

Whenever we sees a thing the process happening at atomic level is the electrons of that stuff absorbs the energy from packets and goes to higher state and then comes to ground state and emits radiation
But my question is what if that stuff don't have electrons like $ H^+$ is there any way we can detect it (Not by some kind of chemical reaction) and if yes then which nature of light can explain it perfectly

Comment: protons still have charge, which means photons and charged particles interact with them. They are fairly easy to detect. [Neutron detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_detection) is a thing too. One doesn't need a theory of light to explain how to detect things that don't have electrons

Comment: Okay so you are saying that we can detect things like proton, neutron by using light so can you please explain what's going on there

Comment: The stuff would have the appearance of a metal... at 2000 times longer wavelengths, i.e. it would strongly reflect around several hundred GHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to detect single particle radiation, charged or not. Scintillation counters can use photomultiplier tubes to detect single particles, single protons, neutrons, positrons, uncharged gamma rays etc. It depends on them having enough energy to ionize the material used for the scintillation.

Plenty other ways, for instance a modified version of MRI can detect single protons. There is also methods for detecting low energy particles, even uncharged low energy neutrinos which are hard to detect. See for instance http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.nucl.46.1.471?journalCode=nucl

What is hard to detect are particles that have weaker interactions with matter or fields. Neutrinos are hard to detect, because they interact only through the weak interactions. Many particles are 'detected' by observing their decay products, as was the Higgs boson detected. Dark matter has still not been detected as single particles (nor in the bulk really except for astrophysical quantities that exert gravitational attraction) because they interact only through gravity and probably weak interactions.

Overall then it mostly depends on the strength of the interactions and the energy levels involved. If that had not been true we would have never detected and verified any other elementary particle.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the interaction of matter with light is dominated by electrons because they are lighter and this makes their coupling with light stronger than that of nuclei. However, this doesn't mean that nuclei cannot interact with light: they are still electrically charged particles, and they do interact with electromagnetic radiation to some extent.

On the other hand, your proposal of having a pure $\mathrm H^+$ sample is not workable because it will simply explode. At standard pressure and temperature, atomic hydrogen has a density of ${\sim}41\: \mu\mathrm{g /cm^3}$; if you took a cubic centimetre at that density and took away all the electrons, you'd have a total charge of ${\sim}3.95\:\mathrm C$ in that cubic centimetre, and this would have an electrostatic potential energy of around 3.22 kilotons of TNT, putting it just below the Little Boy nuclear bomb - and it *is* energy which would be immediately, and explosively, released. That's obviously an extreme example, but in general it's very hard to accrue anything like a macroscopic amount of truly charged matter.

However, you can still imagine, for example, a sample of antiprotonic hydrogen (hydrogen atoms with the electrons replaced by antiprotons), in which there are no electrons. (The sample will still explode, of course, at about 1.75 tons of TNT per cubic centimetre at STP, but it's more of a reasonable experiment as it's somewhat easier to ignore matter-antimatter annihilation than it is to forget that like charges repel.) In this case, the sample will still interact perfectly well with light: the overall response will be weaker, because of the higher mass of each interacting particle, but only by a finite amount, and both the protons and antiprotons will contribute equally to the response.